# Calling function from another Python file

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, rfid

I am trying to call a function from another Python file after a button is click. I have imported the file and used the FileName.fuctionName() to run the function. The problem is my exception keeps catching. I am guessing that the data from the function being called is not being grabbed.What I am trying to do is have a user fill out a Tkinter gui then click a button. Once the button is click the user will then be asked to scan their tag (rfid) and that data will then be sent to a firebase real time database which will store the user's inputted info along with the card_id and user_id that was created when the tag was scanned.

Im kinda at a loss because other than the exception catching I am not getting any other errors, any thoughts? I have posted the code below along with comments.

**error :** *local variable 'user_id' referenced before assignment*

```
from tkinter import *
#Second File
import Write
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from firebase import firebase

data = {}

global user_id

# Firebase 
firebase= firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/",None)

# button click
def sub ():
    global user_id

    #setting Variables from user input
    name = entry_1.get()
    last = entry_2.get()
    number = phone.get()
 
    try:
        #Calling Function from other file
        Write.scan()
        if Write.scan():
            #getting the New User Id
            user_id= new_id

        
            #User Info being sent to the Database 
            data = {
            'Name #': name,
            'Last': last,
            'Number': number,
            'Card #':user_id
            }
        results = firebase.post('xxxxxxxx/User',data)
               
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)    

# setting main frame
root = Tk()
root.geometry('850x750')
root.title("Registration Form")

label_0 = Label(root, text="Registration form",width=20,font=("bold", 20))
label_0.place(x=280,y=10)

label_1 = Label(root, text="First Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80,y=65)

entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240,y=65)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Last Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_2.place(x=68,y=95)

entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_2.place(x=240,y=95)

phoneLabel = Label(root, text="Contact Number : ",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
phoneLabel.place(x=400,y=65)

phone = Entry(root)
phone.place(x=550,y=65)

Button(root, text='Submit',command = sub,width=20,bg='brown',fg='white').place(x=180,y=600)

root.mainloop()
```

**Write.py** file being Imported

```
import string
from random import*
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

#Function being called
def scan():
    try:
        #Creating user hash
        c = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
        new_id = "".join(choice(c) for x in range(randint(25,25)))
        print("Please Scan tag")
    
        #Writing to tag
        reader.write(new_id)
        if reader.write(new_id):
            print("Tag Scanned")
        
        else:
            print("Scan Tag First")
        print("Scanning Complete")
    
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: Try adding this to your `except` and then paste the error code with the code. `except Exception as e:   print(e)`. What i think is, `Write.scan()` does not take any arguments, while you gave `True`.

Comment: @CoolCloud that seemed to point me in the right direction. The error I am getting now is : _scan() takes 0 positional argument but 1 was given_

Comment: exactly, as ive mentioned, what do you mean by `Write.scan(True)` and `Write.scan(op)`. Your implementation of function into another module is fine, but your definition of function is whats causing the error

Comment: @CoolCloud the `Write.scan(True)` is used to check if tag is being scanned and `Write.scan(op)` is used to grab the newly generated user id. I am trying to get the user id after it has been generated so I can store it in the data base. The user id and card id will only be generated once the user scans their tag.

Comment: I think you should revise your definition, like `def scan(status,op):` this way your passing in two parameters like a boolean `status` and `op`, im not sure how to go forward with it though

Comment: I thought about calling the database reference in the Write.py instead. But ill mess around with passing two parameters, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the value `new_id` in one file isn't going to influence the value with the same name in the other file, for a similar reason as for the first problem.  In both places it appears, `new_id` is a local variable that only exists in the enclosing function.

Another issue I see is that you're calling Write.scan() twice in a row. Do you mean to be calling it twice?  I expect not.

Also, you're testing the return value of `Write.scan()`, but that function doesn't return a value. So I think that the code in the `if` block in the first file will never run.

Globals are a bad idea in general, as they're easy to get wrong and they tend to obscure what the code is really doing.  "Never say never", but I'll say that I very rarely find the need for a global variable in Python.  In your case, I think it would be much better to have `Write.scan()` return the value of the new user id instead of passing it back as a global. Since you're testing the value of `Write.scan()`, maybe this is what you were thinking of doing already.  Here are the changes I'd make to address these three issues and hopefully get your code working the way you want...

```
...

def sub ():
    
    ...
    
    try:
        #Calling Function from other file
        new_id = Write.scan()
        if new_id:
            #getting the New User Id
            user_id= new_id
    
    ...

...

def scan():
    try:
        
        ...
        
        new_id = "".join(choice(c) for x in range(randint(25,25)))
        
        ...

        return new_id

    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks man, Iv been trying to figure that out for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell what your problem is, because there is no place in your code that references `user_id` and hence the error message you cite can't come from the code you provide.  However, I see a pretty common mistake that your code appears to be making that could very well account for why you expect `user_id` to be defined somewhere in your code and yet it is not...

In your first block of code, the global `user_id` is not being set by the `sub` function.  Rather, when the `sub` function calls `user_id=new_id`, it is creating and setting a variable that is local to that function.  When that function ends, the result of that call is lost and the global `user_id` is still undefined.

What you want is to define `user_id` as being global inside of the sub() function.  Just add `global user_id` anywhere near the top of the function definition.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
global x

def sub():
    x = 3
    
sub()
print(x)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t", line 7, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

whereas:

```
global x

def sub():
    global x
    x = 3
    
sub()
print(x)
```

result:

```
3
```

Comment: I have added the changes that you suggested and it worked kinda. The code runs on with no errors. However, nothing happens after the card is scanned. I dont think the `try` function is grabbing the created uid. This is because the data base is not being updated after the tag is scan.

Comment: I'm again not positive what you're saying, but I do see that the value `new_id` in one file isn't going to influence the value with the same name in the other file, for a similar reason as for the first problem.  You want to 1) declare `new_id` as global at the top level, and then 2) put the line `global new_id` before the line `new_id = "".join(choice(c) for x in range(randint(25,25)))` in the second file.  As it is now, your setting of `new_id` is lost when the `scan()` method exits.

Comment: I see some other issues as well.  First of all, you're calling `Write.scan()` twice in a row.  Do you mean to be calling it twice? Also, you're testing the return value of `Write.scan()`, but that function doesn't return a value.  So I think that the code in the `if` block in the first file will never run.